# ¿Como hago para hacer hover en un div, y el botón aparezca encima de todo?

Tags: botón, hover

Tengo un div que al hacer hover, cambia de color a negro con opacidad.
Dentro de este div, tengo un botón de "VER MÁS" que quiero que aparezca encima del color negro que aparece de fondo.
Ahora mismo me aparece debajo del fondo.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center coleccion-left coleccion-hover" id="coleccion-principal" style="background: #006837;">
    <a class="btn-colecciones" href="/moda/">VER MÁS</a>
    <div class="colecciones-moda-img col-img-hover"></div>
    <div class="colecciones-moda-text colecciones-text text-white">MODA</div>
</div>


    #coleccion-principal:hover{
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      filter:brightness(0.4);
      z-index: 10 !important;
      position: relative;
    }
        
    .btn-colecciones{
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 40%;
          width: 150px;
          height: 50px;
          border: 2px solid #fff;
          background: none;
          color: #fff;
          transform:  translate(.50%, -50%);
        }

    .coleccion-hover:hover > .btn-colecciones{
      display: block;
      padding-top: 10px;
      z-index: 99999 !important;
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y veo que el boton "ver mas", aparece encima. ¿Puedes revisarlo?
https://jsfiddle.net/02kgLb7u/

Comment: Si te fijas, al hacer hover se ve el borde y el texto de botón gris, y en teoría es blanco. Eso es porque se ve la opacidad negra de la capa que tiene encima. Lo que necesito finalmente es ver el borde y el texto de color blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que le estás aplicando un filtro al elemento padre, y no hay manera de quitar ese efecto del elemento hijo. Por eso te sale con una reducción del brillo.

La solución es, que le apliques ese efecto solo a los elementos que te interesen. Para ello, utiliza los selectores hijos:

```
#coleccion-principal:hover > .colecciones-moda-img,
#coleccion-principal:hover > .colecciones-moda-text{
  //propiedades
}
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```css
#coleccion-principal {
  position: relative;
}
#coleccion-principal:hover > .colecciones-moda-img,
#coleccion-principal:hover > .colecciones-moda-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  filter: brightness(0.6);
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.btn-colecciones {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}

.coleccion-hover:hover > .btn-colecciones {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.colecciones-moda-img > img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.colecciones-moda-img,
.colecciones-moda-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center coleccion-left coleccion-hover" id="coleccion-principal" style="background: #006837;">
    <a class="btn-colecciones" href="/moda/">VER MÁS</a>
    <div class="colecciones-moda-img col-img-hover">
    <img src="https://www.foromarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/La-moda-l%C3%ADquida.png">
    </div>
    <div class="colecciones-moda-text colecciones-text text-white">MODA</div>
</div>
```